# Local Planner Creation

Tags: navigation, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'd like to create a local planner which implements the vfh algorithm and substitute it in the navigation stack.
Any suggestion from where I can start or about previous work about it.
I saw that I should use the interface BaseLocalPlanner of nav_core.
But how can i substitute it when it is finished?
I can't figure out wher to specify which local planner I want to use.
Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61256/local-planner-creation/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2013-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can start by taking a look at the CarrotPlanner local planner, it is one of the most simple and you can build from there.
To specify a planner different from the default ones, you can add one of these lines to a launch file, where you launch the move_base node.

```
  ## alternative global planners ##
  <!-- <param name="base_global_planner" value="goal_passer/GoalPasser"/> -->
  <!-- <param name="base_global_planner" value="carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner"/> -->
  <!-- <param name="base_global_planner" value="SBPLLatticePlanner"/>-->

  ## alternative local planners ##
  <!-- <param name="base_local_planner" value="pose_follower/PoseFollower"/> -->
  <!-- <param name="base_local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS"/> -->
  <!-- <param name="base_local_planner" value="eband_local_planner/EBandPlannerROS"/> -->
```

For example:

```
<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
  <param name="base_global_planner" value="goal_passer/GoalPasser"/>
  <param name="controller_frequency" value="10.0" />
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2013-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2013-04-21**:
Thank you for your suggestion, it is really helpful. But isn't the carrot planner a global planner?

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2013-04-21**:
Indeed.  Sorry, in that case you can begin with the PoseFollower and also take a look into the other local planners to have an idea on how to build your own.

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-17**:
@Procópio Silveira Stein I need to be able to navigate in an environment with moving people and avoid them do you have any idea how to accomplish it? Thanks